# Validating Identifier Using Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex, validation

Hello I am struggling with what to return from my final isValid method I basically need to check if an email address is valid or not please any and all help is appreciated.

```
public class EmailAddress {

    private static final String x = "[a - z]";
    private static final String y = "[a-z0-9]";
    private static final String id = x + y;

  private String address;

    public EmailAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

  /**
   * Verify that a string is an email address.
   * The string must obey the following (somewhat strict format)
   * <email>      ::= <identifier> @ <identifier> {. <identifier>}
   * <identifier> ::= letter { letter | digit }
   **/
  public boolean isValid() {

      if (address == null) return false;
      String check = (id + "@" + id + "{." + id + "}" );
      return
  }
}
```

This is my JUtil Test Code:

```
public class TestEmail {

  private EmailAddress address;

  @Test
  public void replaceMe() {
    assertTrue(true);
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldAcceptJohnAtCsDotEdu() {
    EmailAddress ea = new EmailAddress("john@cs.edu");
    assertTrue( ea.isValid() );
  }
  @Test
  public void shouldNotAccept123AtCsDotEdu() {
    EmailAddress ea = new EmailAddress("123@cs.edu");
    assertFalse( ea.isValid() );
  }
}
```

Edit: This is the test code that I've made for the project

Comment: I know it's something silly I am just absolutely stuck maybe it's because it's late. I think I should be checking something else? I can also post my test file.

Answer (score 0):

**Think about this.** What does a "valid" email mean to you?

I've written an email validator using regular expressions before<sup>*</sup>, which adhered (for the most part) to [RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt), which explicitly defines what a valid email actually *is*.

Email validation is **complex**, as there are a lot of components and parts.  Ultimately, it may be easier to simply send the email to the end user to determine if it's valid or not; if they can reply to it, then it's valid.

But, if you want to write a simple validator, define your scope:

- Are you accepting any gTLD?
- Are you accepting emails with the + character embedded in it?  (It's valid and a shame most services don't accept it)
- Do you care about the width?

From *there*, you can build a validator.  But, you have to narrow your scope.  There's a lot of stuff to check in an email, and there are some obvious things that could be checked without sending off an email (i.e. no TLD).

But you should really narrow your scope.

<sup>*:  Yes, I sorely regret this fact.</sup>